# Window not selected after changing frame from using a button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

When I change scene with the use of a button in my game it seems to deselect the window. Then it does not respond to keyboard input without clicking the window again afterwards.

Is there a way to stop this with some sort of command or a way to bypass this with a different method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click an object that object gains focus. During your buttons MouseEvent.CLICK event listener, you need to call the setFocus() function on the object you need the key strokes on.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to set the focus to the stage?

Comment: Call stage.focus = null; that should clear the focus and reset it to the stage itself.